# Move cursor past span on content editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a tag entering system for a template builder. Right now I am trying to help my editor "know" the difference between regular text and formatted text because right now I am making it so it is similar to WordPress shortcodes where a templated element would be something like `[shortcode]` But the issue I am running into right now is that my div's cursor includes any text typed after an inserted shortcode into the styled div as well.

```js
$(function() {
  /**
   * Position tracking.
   */
  class PositionTracker {
    constructor(start, end) {
      this.start = start;
      this.end = end;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Variable insert selector
   * @type {jQuery|HTMLElement}
   */
  const $selector = $("#variableSelector");
  /**
   * Message content editor
   * @type {jQuery|HTMLElement}
   */
  const $body = $("#bodyContent");
  /**
   * Message Recorder
   * @type {jQuery|HTMLElement}
   */
  const $recorder = $('#bodyRecorder');


  /**
   * Position of cursor
   * @type {PositionTracker}
   */
  const position = new PositionTracker(0, 0);

  $selector.on('change', function() {
    let content = $body.html();
    let tag = $('<span>', {
      class: 'text-tag',
      text: $(this).val().toString()
    });
    $body.append(tag);
  });
  $body.on('input mousedown mouseup mouseout', function() {
    $recorder.val($(this).html);
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    position.start = selection.anchorOffset;
    position.end = selection.focusOffset;
  });

});
```

```css
.text-editor {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 10px 8px;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  line-height: 1.35;
  color: #000;
  border: solid 1px rgba(6, 26, 45, 0.65);
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 6px rgba(4, 24, 39, 0.35);
}

.text-editor:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.text-editor[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  color: darkgray;
  content: attr(placeholder);
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
  /* For Firefox */
}

.text-editor.body {
  min-height: 170px;
}

.text-tag {
  background: rgba(0, 195, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="content" type="hidden" id="contentRecoreder" required="required">
  <div id="bodyContent" contenteditable="true" class="content-body text-editor" placeholder="Hi [customer-name], this is [my-name] with [my-company]. We can do that job for just [quote-price]. If you have any questions, call or text us at [my-phone]"></div>

  <label>Variables</label>
  <select name="variables" id="variableSelector">
    <option value="empty">(choose one)</option>
    <option value="[customer-name]">Customer Name</option>
    <option value="[my-name]">My Name</option>
    <option value="[my-company]">My Company</option>
    <option value="[my-price" ]>Quote Price</option>
    <option value="[my-phone]">My Phone</option>
  </select>

  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be other ways to achieve this - but one simple way would be to add the `contenteditable` attribute to your span element and set its value to `false` - noting this has to be done after you have populated it with your `shortcode` value.

Note whilst this does not "move the cursor" it does prevent any text typed after an inserted shortcode going into the styled span. Which when you think about it is probably what you actually want - otherwise your `shotcode` tags would be editable by simply clicking into them an typing.

e.g.

```js
$(function() {
  /**
   * Position tracking.
   */
  class PositionTracker {
    constructor(start, end) {
      this.start = start;
      this.end = end;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Variable insert selector
   * @type {jQuery|HTMLElement}
   */
  const $selector = $("#variableSelector");
  /**
   * Message content editor
   * @type {jQuery|HTMLElement}
   */
  const $body = $("#bodyContent");
  /**
   * Message Recorder
   * @type {jQuery|HTMLElement}
   */
  const $recorder = $('#bodyRecorder');


  /**
   * Position of cursor
   * @type {PositionTracker}
   */
  const position = new PositionTracker(0, 0);

  $selector.on('change', function() {
    let content = $body.html();
    let tag = $('<span>', {
      class: 'text-tag',
      text: $(this).val().toString()
    });
    // prevent editing of the span content
    tag.attr('contenteditable', false);
    $body.append(tag);
  });
  $body.on('input mousedown mouseup mouseout', function() {
    $recorder.val($(this).html);
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    position.start = selection.anchorOffset;
    position.end = selection.focusOffset;
  });

});
```

```css
.text-editor {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 10px 8px;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  line-height: 1.35;
  color: #000;
  border: solid 1px rgba(6, 26, 45, 0.65);
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 6px rgba(4, 24, 39, 0.35);
}

.text-editor:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.text-editor[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  color: darkgray;
  content: attr(placeholder);
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
  /* For Firefox */
}

.text-editor.body {
  min-height: 170px;
}

.text-tag {
  background: rgba(0, 195, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="content" type="hidden" id="contentRecoreder" required="required">
  <div id="bodyContent" contenteditable="true" class="content-body text-editor" placeholder="Hi [customer-name], this is [my-name] with [my-company]. We can do that job for just [quote-price]. If you have any questions, call or text us at [my-phone]"></div>

  <label>Variables</label>
  <select name="variables" id="variableSelector">
    <option value="empty">(choose one)</option>
    <option value="[customer-name]">Customer Name</option>
    <option value="[my-name]">My Name</option>
    <option value="[my-company]">My Company</option>
    <option value="[my-price" ]>Quote Price</option>
    <option value="[my-phone]">My Phone</option>
  </select>

  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Edit (see comments):

[image: showing multiple tags]

Comment: This won't work well because I still need the ability to put more than one tag, and once I put one down, we run into issues where it splits

Comment: @TylerLazenby Not quite sure what you mean...I am able to enter multiple "non-editable" tags fine using this. See the image in my edit. Not sure what you mean by "splits".